# React, how to modify the state of a parent component

Tags: reactjs

As you will see in the code below I have my main App component, which has 3 states, and a child component, SerchBar, which will render several buttons, I want to use those buttons to fill the championsFilter state with the ones that the champions state will have

```
class App extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount(){
    fetch("http://ddragon.leagueoflegends.com/cdn/12.20.1/data/en_US/champion.json")
    .then(data => data.json())
    .then(champs => {
      this.setState({
        champions : Object.values(champs.data),     
      })    
    })   
  }

  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      champions: [],
      championsFilter: [],
      championDetail : {}
    }
  } 
  
  render(){
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <h1>clone of League of legends champions, to practice React Js</h1>
        <NavBar/>
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/">
            <SearchBar rols={rols}/>
            <Champions champions={this.state.champions}/>
          </Route>
          <Route path="/form">
            <Form/>
          </Route>
          <Route path="/detail">
            <Detail/>
          </Route>
          <Route path="/about">
            <About/>
          </Route>
        </Switch>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To modify the state of parent component you can make use of **callback function**.

Try this :

1. Create a function in parent component which is App and send this function as a props to SearchBar

Ex :

```
const getSearchValue = (championsFilter) => {

// In here championsFilter will have the value from child component

}

<SearchBar rols={rols} getSearchValue = {() => getSearchValue(championsFilter)}/>
```

2. In SearchBar component, on the button click event handler, you can push all the button values i.e search values and store it in an array and then call the props function getSearchValue and pass this array as a parameter.

Ex :

```
const onClick = () => {
// write your logic to push the search field values to an array here, Example code 

let filterArray = [];
filterArray.push("searchField");

this.props.getSearchValue(filterArray)
}
```